# Cygwin Heap Space Error

Tags: bash, cygwin, sh, ash

I'm receiving an error when I try to run any cygwin functionality (bash/sh/ash/dash), which says:
`1 [main] ash 5008 D:\DevStudio\cygwin\bin\ash.exe: *** fatal error - could
n't allocate heap, Win32 error 487, base 0xC80000, top 0xCD0000, reserve_size 32
3584, allocsize 327680, page_const 4096
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028E4EC  6102796B  (0028E4EC, 00000000, 00000000, 00640000)
0028E7DC  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
0028F80C  61004F1B  (611B66CC, 00C80000, 00CD0000, 0004F000)
0028F83C  6106E8C3  (7FFEFFFF, 000000FF, 00000008, 77C2FEA2)
0028F92C  610C133B  (00000078, 02000000, 6116A724, 6116A720)
0028F95C  610064C0  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FA1C  6106FC15  (61000000, 00000001, 0028FD24, 00000001)
0028FA3C  77C4B990  (6106F960, 61000000, 00000001, 0028FD24)
0028FB30  77C50389  (0028FD24, 7EFDD000, 7EFDE000, 77D1206C)
0028FCB0  77C56C5C  (0028FD24, 77C10000, 597A2CBD, 00000000)
0028FD00  77C55717  (0028FD24, 77C10000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FD10  77C4BEB9  (0028FD24, 77C10000, 00000000, 0001002F)
End of stack trace
      0 [main] ash 6536 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initial
ization, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11`

I've looked at suggestions which all suggest rebasing, however it just fails with the above error but with this added on:

```
/usr/bin/rebaseall: 21: Cannot fork
```

Any help would be great! I've tried changing virtual memory size etc with no avail. Sophos is also running on this machine.

Comment: Clean re-install, copy user files?

Comment: Feel like an idiot, thanks!